# Find the parity outlier Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My function fails (returns undefined) when the answer is a negative odd number only.
Otherwise it works.
Can anyone see why?

Instructions:

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

My code:

```
function findOutlier(integers) {
  let binary = integers.map((int, i) => int % 2);
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    if (binary[i] == 0)
      count++;
  }
  if (count > 1) {
    return integers[binary.indexOf(1)]
  } else {
    return integers[binary.indexOf(0)]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you passing for `integers` in the failing case?

Comment: Your best bet here is to use the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE and put a breakpoint on the return statements. Probably it would be best to split out the calls to `indexOf` so you can find out which one isn't returning what you're expecting (it would appear to be returning `-1`, and of course, `integers[-1]` is `undefined`).

Comment: It's worth noting that your function makes up to three passes through the data (one full pass for `map`, another full pass for your `for` loop, a third probably-partial pass in `indexOf`), even though the assignment says *"...but could be very large..."* which suggests you might want to avoid that where you can. But there's never any need to go more than two places beyond the outlier to know where it is (that would be if the outlier is the first entry) and in most cases, you'll know where it is as soon as you encounter it (because you'll have seen at least two odds or evens beforehand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript `%` operator returns negative numbers in certain cases (when the left-hand side is negative and the right is positive). Thus your `.indexOf(1)` won't find the `-1` in the array.

You could fix it in the `.map()` callback by using `(i) => i & 1` to directly check the least-significant bit.

If it were me, I would interpret the warning in the assignment that the array could be "very large" as a warning that iteration should be minimized. Thus I'd be tempted to approach the problem differently.  Once you've seen more than one even number or more than one odd number, you can assume that the first number that doesn't fit the pattern is the outlier. (Oh, and it occurs to me that the provision that the array always has at least 3 elements is another hint at the desired solution: you only need to check the first 3 elements to determine whether the input array is almost-all-even or almost-all-odd.)

So maybe something like:

```
function outlier(integers) {
  function par(i) { return i & 1; }

  let parity = par(integers[0]);
  if (parity != par(integers[1])) {
    if (parity == par(integers[2]))
      // [0] and [2] are the true parity so [1] is the outlier
      return integers[1];

    // [1] and [2] are the true parity so [0] is the outlier
    return integers[0];
  }
  return integers.find((i) => par(i) != parity);
}
```

Comment: For instance, if one of `integers` is `-3` or any other odd negative number.

Comment: Great answer.
I am not familiar with the `(i) => i & 1` syntax. Is this returning 2 values?
Could you point me in the right direction to read up on this?

Comment: @PDJ the `&` (single  `&`, not `&&`) is the binary AND operator. By using it with 1 on the right hand side, the result will be either 0 or 1 because only when the lowest bit in the left-side is also 1 will the AND give 1. Thus a 1 means it's odd, and 0 means it's even.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `%` will return negative numbers when you use negative numbers on left hand side of `%`.

For example `-3%2 = -1`.

To handle such case you can change your code like:

```
function findOutlier(integers) {
  let binary = integers.map((int, i) => Math.abs(int) % 2 );
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    if (binary[i] == 0)
      count++;
  }
  if (count > 1) {
    return integers[binary.indexOf(1)]
  } else {
    return integers[binary.indexOf(0)]
  }
}
```

This can work but there are better ways to solve the above problem with better time complexity. As mentioned in other answers(You only need 3 passes to decide outlier will be even or odd)

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the storing of the first two indices of either odd (`false`) or even (`true`) values and exit early if at least two of one and one of the other type is found.

```js
const isEven = value => value % 2 === 0;

function find(array) {
    var indices = { true: [], false: [] },
        i, key;
        
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        key = isEven(array[i]);
        if (indices[key].length < 2) indices[key].push(i);
        if (indices.true.length > 1 && indices.false.length === 1) return indices.false[0];
        if (indices.false.length > 1 && indices.true.length === 1) return indices.true[0];
    }
    return indices;
}

console.log(find([1, 0, 0]));
console.log(find([0, 1, 0]));
console.log(find([0, 0, 1]));
console.log(find([0, 1, 1]));
console.log(find([1, 0, 1]));
console.log(find([1, 1, 0]));
```